# justify-content isn't working - flexbox problem

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am working on the following code:

```css
.positiones {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="positiones">
  <div class="mainheading">
    <h1>The biggest startup event of the year!</h1><br>
  </div><br>
</div>
<div class="linebreak"></div><br>

<div class="Button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get more info</button><br>
</div>
```

as you can see, the justify-content property isn't working.

well, I need some help, thank you:)

Comment: are you talking about the button ?

Comment: Your code works fine. You have flex container `positiones` with one item `mainheading` in it. What exactly do you want to center? `h1` or `h1`&`button`?

Comment: `justify-content` is working properly. `mainheading` is justified to center. What behaviour are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.button not inside the .positiones. i put inside the .positiones. And i add `flex-direction:column`

```css
.positiones {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction:column;
}
```

```html
<div class="positiones">
  <div class="mainheading">
    <h1>The biggest startup event of the year!</h1><br>
  </div>
  <div class="Button">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get more info</button><br>
</div>
</div>
<div class="linebreak"></div><br>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean centre the button under the heading:

```css
 .positiones {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.button {
  display:block;
  margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div class="positiones">
  <div>
    <h1>The biggest startup event of the year!</h1>
    <button class="button" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Get more info</button>
  </div>
</div>
```